# Oracle To Postgres, MySQL or MS Access Migration

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql, ms-access, migration

I have an Oracle 8i database running on 2000 NT server.

I have been assigned a task to copy data along with schema into any of these

(postgresql, mysql, ms access)

I have tried a lot in the internet but there is no such tool which could help me. Right now I am running that NT 2000 in virtual machine using VM WARE.

Answer (score 1):

It is not too difficult to link Oracle to MS Access, from which point it is just a matter of running queries, if you need the data to be physically held in MS Access.

More info: http://www.orafaq.com/node/60

Answer (score 1):

For copying the schema/data to PostgreSQL there is [ora2pg](http://ora2pg.darold.net/). If this is a recurring task then one nice thing about ora2pg is that you can potentially script/automate the process.

For a one-time or ad-hock export, and depending on the nature and size of the database, you can also use [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) to export the schemas/data.